# Compiler arguments from tex file

Tags: xetex, compiling, kile

I have several times, in different lines of investigation, seen insinuations that adding something along the lines of

```
%& -output-directory=../output 
\documentclass{...}
```

in the very beginning of my main `.tex` file will allow you to, from within the document, pass command line arguments to your compiler. The code above doesn't work for me, though, and I can't seem to find any good documentation.

Is this a common practice? How do you do it right? How does it work?

I write in Kile, and compile with XeLaTeX.
EDIT: ...on Ubuntu.

Comment: I believe it works that way only with MiKTeX (on Windows).

Comment: So this is an editor thing? That at least is a new angle of attack.

Comment: No, MiKTeX is a TeX distribution, independent of whatever editor you use.

Comment: One cross platform possibility would be to use something like arara which can read comments at the head of the file and set up a pipeline of commands

Comment: Kile cannot do this. Kile also ignores the more standard `% !TEX TS-program = pdflatex` lines which many editors recognise. You can specify things like this for compilation commands (i.e. not per-document). However, that does not work at all well in current versions of Kile. (There are bugs which made it unusable for me.) `arara` works beautifully, however, and is editor independent which is, I think, an advantage.